# Configure Nginx to add subfolder

Tags: nginx

I have an running nginx instance with the below config.  Right now, this is resolving to the root URL of the server.  How do I change the config so that it resolved to http://serverIP/FolderName instead of http://serverIP

```
 Server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www;

        index /_h5ai/server/php/index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        location /_h5ai/ {
                root /usr/share/h5ai/;

                location /_h5ai/server/php/index.php {
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }
}
```

(Sorry for the stupid question, I'm just learning nginx)

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Just tell, what URL should go to which directory on the server?

Comment: I want the user to visit the URL at http://serverIP/FolderName and have it resolve to the same place that the current config is resolving, which I believe is at /usr/share/h5ai/_h5ai/.  The current confix is resolving at http://serverIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www;

    index /_h5ai/server/php/index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location /FolderName {
        alias /usr/share/h5ai/_h5ai/;
    }

    location /FolderName/server/php/index.php {
        alias /usr/share/h5ai/_h5ai/;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I now realize that I originally didn't post the full config file.  I cut off two lines at the top.  I just updated it.  I think that matters here because there was already a root directory that conflicts with the one in your file.  The var/www folder is a storage folder for the web app.  Thoughts?  Thanks so much for the help.  It's very much appreciated.

Comment: I updated the suggestion according to your update.

Comment: After applying the above and then restarting the server, I'm getting a 404 when I visit http://serverIP/FolderName/.  I don't want to both you any more though.  Thanks so much for the help thus far.

Comment: I made one more update to the answer. Since you are using IP address to access the server, you need to apply the configuration to the default server block in nginx. You might have `default_server` configured elsewhere, you need to modify it and remove `default_server`.